# Cross thread operation not valid

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

im trying to access a rich textbox on another form im using the following code to do so:

```
Private Delegate Sub StringDelegateChat(text As String, window As ChatWindow)
    Private Sub AppendTextChatWindows(text As String, window As ChatWindow)
        Try              
            If window.RichTextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
                window.Invoke(New StringDelegateChat(AddressOf AppendTextChatWindows), text, window)
            Else
                window.RichTextBox1.AppendText(text)
                window.RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = window.RichTextBox1.Text.Length
                window.RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

but i get the cross thread operation not valid error, i think it does this because it misses out the `window.invoke` part of the if statement. i also tried replacing the`If window.RichTextBox1.InvokeRequired Then`  to `If InvokeRequired Then` but it gets caught in a continues loop and a stack overflow error is thrown.

Thanks
Houlahan

Comment: Tried already window.InvokeRequired  instead of window.RichTextBox1.InvokeRequired?

Comment: yea that just skips to the else and then trows the exception :/

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the controls handle has been created? Even if you are, it might not hurt to double check...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe, on line 5, `window.Invoke` should be changed to `window.RichTextBox1.Invoke`.

```
Private Delegate Sub StringDelegateChat(text As String, window As ChatWindow)
Private Sub AppendTextChatWindows(text As String, window As ChatWindow)
    Try
        If window.RichTextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
            window.RichTextBox1.Invoke(New StringDelegateChat(AddressOf AppendTextChatWindows), text, window)
        Else
            window.RichTextBox1.AppendText(text)
            window.RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = window.RichTextBox1.Text.Length
            window.RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
    Private Sub AppendTextChatWindows(text As String, window As ChatWindow)
        Try              
            If window.RichTextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
                window.RichTextBox1.BeginInvoke(New StringDelegateChat(AddressOf AppendTextChatWindows), text, window)
                Exit Sub 
            Else
                window.RichTextBox1.AppendText(text)
                window.RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = window.RichTextBox1.Text.Length
                window.RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Basically, I am asking about BeginInvoke rather than Invoke.  Although I would expect, as another poster mentioned, that you should be using the same thing you check the required against to invoke.  (ie both window.invokeRequired & window.BeginInvoke or the control)

Answer (score 0):

I cant see any errors in your code. You might want to check for any events that are fired when updating the RichTextbox. They might be causing a cross threading.

As a workaround to your problem, working with objects, you are less likely o encounter cross threading problems.