# Threading and Background Worker

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, background, worker

I'm trying to make something that checks Xbox Usernames, but I tried to do so with a timer, which lags the UI of it. So I figured I do it with a background worker, but with the different threads, and calling UI references isn't really working out for me. Any help?

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count
        Using Wc As New WebClient()
            Try
                Dim Xbox As String = String.Empty
                Xbox = Wc.DownloadString("http://www.xboxgamertag.com/search/" & ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())

                If Xbox.Contains("Online Status") Then
                    FlatAlertBox1.Text = "Gamertag " & ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString & " is taken :("
                    FlatAlertBox1.kind = FlatAlertBox._Kind.Error
                    FlatAlertBox1.Visible = True
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                FlatAlertBox1.Text = "Gamertag " & ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString & " is not taken!"
                FlatAlertBox1.kind = FlatAlertBox._Kind.Success
                FlatAlertBox1.Visible = True
            End Try

        End Using
    Next
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex += 1
```

When I try to run it, I get:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ListBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

On the line :  `FlatAlertBox1.Text = "Gamertag " & ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString & " is not taken!"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743675/cross-thread-operation-not-valid

Comment: if your on 2012 or 2013 then you can use [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx) to do the fetch asynchronously and stop it blocking the ui thread without using threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update GUI controls on a non-UI thread, so you will have to try "reporting" the findings during your loop.

Here I just start the thread with a copy of strings from the ListBox:

```
bgw.RunWorkerAsync(ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String))
```

We need a simple class to report information:

```
Public Class UserStatus
  Property Name As String
  Property Kind As Integer
End Class
```

Then in the DoWork method

```
Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork
  For Each s As String In DirectCast(e.Argument, IEnumerable(Of String))
    Using Wc As New WebClient()
      Dim Xbox As String = String.Empty
      Xbox = Wc.DownloadString("http://www.xboxgamertag.com/search/" & s)
      If Xbox.Contains("Online Status") Then
        bgw.ReportProgress(0, New UserStatus() With {.Name = s, .Kind = Kind.Error})
      Else
        bgw.ReportProgress(0, New UserStatus() With {.Name = s, .Kind = Kind.Success})
      End If
    End Using
  Next
End Sub
```

In the ProgressChanged event, you read your status:

```
Private Sub bgw_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgw.ProgressChanged
  Dim us As UserStatus = DirectCast(e.UserState, UserStatus)
  If us.Kind = Kind.Success Then
    FlatAlertBox1.Text = "Gamertag " & us.Name & " is not taken!"
  Else
    FlatAlertBox1.Text = "Gamertag " & us.Name & " is taken :("
  End If
  FlatAlertBox1.kind = us.Kind
  FlatAlertBox1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

A couple of notes about your code though.  You are looping through a list but placing all your information in the same TextBox, so you are only ever seeing the last item in the list (unless the process is really slow).

I removed the Try-Catch.  If an error occurs in a BackgroundWorker, it will get reported in the RunWorkerCompleted event in the e.Error property.  You should examine any errors that occurred there.

Comment: The only other issue I'm having is reporting back if it's taken or not, in a second text box.